# How does elastic beanstalk update my Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my rails app at [Deploying a Rail Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)

**1)** How can I reset my database as I did on my development environment?

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

**2)** If I create a db migration file, would elastic beanstalk automatically run it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can customize your environment with Elastic Beanstalk Extensions

http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git

Comment: dont get this at all! When is db:create run? Can u explain? Same error shown on my app and when I connect to db its empty.

Comment: This link is outdated at this point. `eb init` does not add any git commands.